# Specify the increase rate of values on a log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot values from an array in a logartihmic plot.

I can achieve this with:

`plt.semilogx(x_centered, arr[start_index:end_index+1], label='Data')`

But what I would like to have is the value of index 1000 in the middle of the plot (on x-axis).
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Would it be possible to add test data for a typical use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the x-axis ticks and labels to ensure that the value at index 1000 appears in the middle of the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate x_centered and arr data
x_centered = np.arange(500, 1501, 1)  # narrower range for demonstration
arr = np.random.rand(len(x_centered))  # example array data

start_index = 0
end_index = len(arr) - 1

# Calculate the midpoint index
midpoint_index = 500  # or 1000 in your case

# Plot the data with a logarithmic x-axis
plt.semilogx(range(len(x_centered)), arr[start_index:end_index+1], label='Data')

# Adjust x-axis ticks and labels
plt.xticks(ticks=[start_index, midpoint_index, end_index], labels=[f'{x_centered[start_index]}', f'{x_centered[midpoint_index]}', f'{x_centered[end_index]}'])

# Add labels and legend
plt.xlabel('X Values')
plt.ylabel('Y Values')
plt.title('Logarithmic Plot with Midpoint at Index 1000')
plt.legend()

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I try to use this with x_centered = np.arange(1,10001,1) and my array as arr it only plots a flat line

Comment: @arturmic, If you’re using np.arange(1, 10001, 1) for x_centered and encountering a flat line when plotting, it’s likely because the range of values in x_centered is too large for a logarithmic scale. When using a logarithmic scale, the values on the x-axis must cover a wide range of orders of magnitude, but they should not start too close to zero. Please check updated code for narrower range.

Answer (score 0):

O.k. it can be done like this:

```
start_index = 100
end_index = 10000

x = np.arange(100,10000,1)


# Plot the values
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.semilogx(x, arr[start_index:end_index+1], label='Data')
plt.title('Data Plot with Index 1000 in the Middle')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```